# rgb/rgba function doesn't work using scss color variables

Tags: sass, dart-sass

I'm currently making the switch to from node-sass to dart-sass. I used to be able to define colour opacity with a mix of hex and rgb like this:

```
$colour-black: #000000;

.element {
    background-color: rgb($colour-black, 0.16);
}
```

However, now it triggers errors and states I'm missing $blue and wants me to provide rgb values

`SassError: Missing element $blue.`

This only works when I give it a strict rgb code like `rgb(0,0,0, .16);` but it won't work if I use `rgb($colour-black, $colour-black, $colour-black, 0.16)`

Is this related to dart-sass or is there something simple I'm missing. Everywhere I've looked it sates I can write rgb codes in scss using hex colour variables. What Am I missing? Thanks for insight you can provide.

`"sass-loader": "^12.1.0",`
`"sass": "^1.48.0",`
`"postcss": "^8.3.9",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `background-color: rgba($colour-black, 0.16);`

You need to use `rgba();` when setting opacity, not `rgb();`

Answer (score 1):

i've encountered same problem. on dart-sass you should put it inside string so you'll need to use interpolation:

```
.element {
    background-color: #{rgba($colour-black, 0.16)};
}
```